# Esper @Name not being picked up by Java

Tags: esper

I have generated an epl file containing the @Name annotation.

When I try to unit test the code, it throws an error saying it cannot locate the @Name statement.

So currently I have

/**********************

*Doing something

**********************/

@Name('test')

insert into SummaryLog

select
.......;

I dont see whats wrong here. My Java code is locating the file and reading it but throws the error as it cannot pick up the @Name.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: Check the statement before @Name('test') and make sure it is correct and properly terminated (;).

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use "@Name('test')" instead of "@('test')". The latter is not an annotation.

Comment: Yes, @Name is in my code, left it out above. My mistake

Comment: What is the exception thrown? (include full stack)